# mongoose schema.create() do not post all schema fields to mongoDb. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So i have a mongo schema as follows;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const adressSchema = require('./entities/adress.entities');
const cardSchema = require('./entities/card.entities');
const UserSchema =  mongoose.Schema ({
    id: {
        type: String,     
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: adressSchema,
        required: true
    },
    creditCards: [cardSchema],
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function (v) {
                return v.length>1 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/.test(v);
            },
            message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid email!`
        },
        phone : {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
            required: true,
            validate: {
                validator: function (v) {
                    return v.length > 1 && /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/.test(v);
                },
                message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
            },
        },
        shippingAddress:[adressSchema],
        role: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
            enum: ['admin', 'user','owner'],
            default: 'user',
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        lastLogin: {
            type: Date,
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['active', 'blocked', 'deleted'],
            default: 'active',
            required: true
        },
        image: String,
    },

},{timestamps: true});

/* -------------------------------- pre save -------------------------------- */
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (this.isNew) {
        this.status = 'active';
        this.role = 'user';
    }
    next();
});

/* ------------------------ create user token object ------------------------ */
UserSchema.virtual('token').get(function () {
    return {
        id: this.id,
        role: this.role,
    };
});

module.exports=  mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

Below is my User Services and Controller

**Service**

```
const UserSchema = require('./users.schema');

module.exports = {
    creatUser: async (data) => {
        try {
            var user = await UserSchema.create({
                username: data.username,
                email: data.email,
                password: data.password,
                phone: data.phone,
                image: data.image,
                address: data.address,
                role: data.role??'user',
                status: data.status??'active',
                shippingAddress: data.shippingAddress??[],
                creditCards: data.creditCards??[],
                lastLogin: data.lastLogin??new Date(),

            });
            return user;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    },
    getUser: async (id) => {
        try {
            const user = await UserSchema.findById(id);
            return user;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    },
    updateUser: async (id, user) => {
        try {
            const updatedUser = await UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, user, { new: true });
            return updatedUser;

        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    },
    login: async (email) => {
        try {
            const user = await UserSchema.findOne({ email });
            return user;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    },
    getUsers: async () => {
        try {
            const users = await UserSchema.find();
            return users;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    },
}
```

**Controller**

```
const userServices = require('./users.service');
const response = require('../../utils/responseHandler.util');
const authMiddleware = require('../../middleware/authentication.middleware');

module.exports ={
    register: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const data = req.body;
           data.password =  authMiddleware.hashPassword(data.password);
            var user = await userServices.creatUser(data);
            if(user){
                user.id = user._id.toString();
                await user.save();
                return response.sendData(res, user);

            }else{
                return response.sendError(res, {message:'Error while creating user'});
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return response.sendError(res, error);
        }
    },
    login: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const {email, password} = req.body;
            const user = await userServices.login(email);
            if(user){
               const isMatch = authMiddleware.comparePassword(password, user.password);
                if(isMatch){
                     const token = authMiddleware.generateToken(user.toObject());
                    return response.sendData(res, {data: user, token: token},'Login successfull');
                }else{
                    return response.sendError(res, {message:'Password not matched'});              
                }

            }else{
                return response.sendError(res, {message:'Email not found'});
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return response.sendError(res, error);
        }
    },
    getUsers: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const users = await userServices.getUsers();
            return response.sendData(res, users);
        } catch (error) {
            return response.sendError(res, error);
        }
    },
    getUser: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const user = await userServices.getUser(id);
            return response.sendData(res, user);
        } catch (error) {
            return response.sendError(res, error);
        }
    },
}
```

Now here is the request i send using Rest Extension
**Request**

```
POST  http://localhost:5000/api/register
Content-Type: application/json

{
"username": "Test User",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"phone": "+23324812548",
"password": "124586",
"address": {"address": "Eben Fashion","city": "Kumasi","country": "Ghana","zipCode": "00233"}
}
```

And here is the response i get
**Response**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Success",
  "data": {
    "username": "Test User",
    "address": {
    },
    "creditCards": [],
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "_id": "65609dce1d69960f898c9716",
    "createdAt": "2023-11-24T12:57:50.482Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-11-24T12:57:50.512Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "65609dce1d69960f898c9716"
  }
}
```

Clearly you could see that the **password and phone** filed was not posted even though they were send from the request. Also other fields such as the **status and the role** were not posted even though they have default values.

**Additional info:**
mongoose: "^8.0.1"
Node v18.18.2

Bellow is the Picture from the mongodb database;
[image]

i have tried using UserSchema.create(data) instead of .create({}) but still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound very funny, but I just noticed that the curly brace for the email validation was enclosing the remaining fields. In simple terms, all the other fields were **inside** the email validation